# Tuning one-class SVM classification R using e1071 ERROR

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am relatively new to SVM in R. I have created an SVM model that works fine with default settings but when I try to use the tune.svm() function to refine the parameters with the same data it throws the following error:

"Error in if (tunecontrol$cross > n) stop(sQuote("cross"), " must not exceed sampling size!") : argument is of length zero"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

The trainingDataFrameNoLabels is a 107*5 dataframe here is the snippets of code I am using.

`

```
install.packages("e1071")
install.packages("raster")
install.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("rgdal")
library("e1071")
library("raster")
require(raster)
trainingData=read.csv(file="Z:/BIO650/Buttomus_Species_Distribution_Model/Working_Data/Training_And_Validation/Training_With_Data.csv",header = TRUE, sep=",")
trainingDataFrame=data.frame(trainingData)
trainingDataFrameNoLabels=trainingDataFrame[,2:6]
svmModel=svm(trainingDataFrameNoLabels,y=NULL, method = "one-classification")
tobj = tune.svm(x=trainingDataFrameNoLabels[1:50,],y=NULL, method = "one-classification",gamma = 10^(-6:-3), nu =  0.001:0.5)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing a list of samples in the tune() call, it will throw this error. I have 1,000 randomly generated samples and I was puzzled too. That's what it was, referencing a list rather than an element. It doesn't know what to do with it. So in my case I randomly selected 1 of the 1,000 sets and used it (in this simplified example of what is more complicated).

```
svm.tune.rslts <- tune(svm, TARGET~., data = aDf_norm.trainsml,nrepeat=8,
                       ranges = list(gamma = 2^(-9:10), cost = 2^(-9:10)),
                       tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "cross",cross=10))

rnd<-sample(1:1000,1)
svm.tune.rslts <- tune(svm, TARGET~., data = aDf_norm.trainsml[[rnd]],nrepeat=8,
                       ranges = list(gamma = 2^(-9:10), cost = 2^(-9:10)),
                       tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "cross",cross=10))
```